# Aegir installation issue

Tags: aegir

While installing Aegir in a VM, during the hostmaster installation, I got the following error:

```
Do you really want to proceed with the install (y/n): y  
PROVISION_SITE_INSTALLED                                             [error]  
The external command could not be executed due to an application     [error]  
error.  
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]  
Error: Unsupported operand types in  
/var/aegir/drush/includes/environment.inc, line 916
```

Drush version 4.5

Comment: any one helps me to sort out this issue....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an issue on Drupal Groups: http://groups.drupal.org/node/96639.

Possible solutions:

- Check if your system is Ubuntu (the installation script assumes that
  it is)
- Remove everything in /var/aegir and run the installation script again.
- Run 'mysql_secure_installation' command and finish it successfully. Aegir
  checks for security flaws during installation and block it if, for
  example, you have anonymous users enabled in mysql.